# What explains the similarities in appearance between Jesus and a certain angel?

Tags: christology, revelation, angels, daniel

The primary physical description for Jesus is [Revelation 1:13-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+1%3A13-15&version=KJV). I noticed that this physical description is essentially identical to the angel in [Daniel 10:5-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel+10%3A5-6&version=KJV) (unnamed, maybe Gabe).

Each is/has:

- Clothed in a long garment, gird in gold
- Fiery eyes
- Brazen extremities
- Many-voiced

The main difference being that the angel’s face is beryl-colored (yellow or blue/green) while Jesus’s face is white

What is at the root of the similarities? Do these features derive from some template of heavenly visitation? Do the individual features have meanings which would have been more clear to a reader in antiquity? Is there any elaboration of the authorial intent here?

Comment: Did you ever serve in the military?  People in that profession wear the same clothes/uniforms, and speak with a similar jargon, but are not the same people.

Comment: It may be helpful to edit your question to specify the viewpoint you're looking for. 
 Different denominations have very different views of angelology and Christology.  For example, Jehovah's Witnesses believe the St Michael the Archangel is Jesus.

Comment: Any viewpoint from any denomination/approach is of interest to me tbh, since the matter seems to be rather niche; I can’t imagine there’s much attention given to the comparison. Primarily, as I assume the author of Revelation must have known about the passage in Daniel, I do wonder what we know of the author’s intent in evoking the similar imagery. (Jehovah’s Witnesses believing Michael is Jesus is very interesting. I wonder if these two visions are cited in defense of that.)

Comment: I'm uncertain the exact justification, though My interpretation would be similar to @KorvinStarmast, where it describes supernatural attire. Angelology has become somewhat of a niche topic, though many of the early church father's wrote about the topic at some length.